# How can I use the loc function with condition on Pandas Series?

Tags: python, pandas, series

so I have a Series looks like this:

```
0 0
1 13
2 100
3 500
```

And I want to return all the numbers that are bigger than 10.

```
1 13
2 100
3 500
```

And I thought using the .loc function but I could not without the column name. I do not want to convert it to dataframe but want to know if it is possible?
Thank you in advance!*emphasized text*

Comment: I guess you missed 13?

Comment: @MehulGupta haha thank you!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
x=pd.Series([0,13,100,500])
x=x[x>10]
```

Answer (score 1):

Suppose s is your series, you can do:

```
s.loc[s.gt(10)]
```